# ACCESS 2007 Does anyone have an example on how to use the Form.ResyncCommand property?

Tags: ms-access-2007

In my case I have an .adp app that is pointing to a sql server database.

I created a form (with a subform) so that I can have a quick way to put some records in a child table. (there is a join between the parent and the child)

I've deduced that (unless I want to write some code, which shouldn't be necessary) I just need to populate the "Resync Command" field in the subform's Property Sheet[image]

MSDN *talks* about it, but gives no examples.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213742(office.12).aspx

without it, when I update my subform (enters a record into the child table) I get the error:

"Key value for this row was changed or deleted at the data store. The local row is now deleted."

update:

**I found THIS, which explains a solution, but I'm not sure what exactly the Sql Statement is trying to do.  Can someone explain this?**

> Error While Inserting Records to a Form
>
> Sometimes when adding a record to an
>   ADP form an error message appears:
>
> “The data was added to the database
>   but the data won't be displayed in the
>   form because it doesn't satisfy the
>   criteria in the underlying record
>   source.”
>
> For this we have to set the
>   ResyncCommand Property of the Form in
>   the design view to a SQL statement.
>
> For Example: Resync Command: Select *
>   From tblName where FieldName = ?
>
> If the Rowsource contains a stored
>   procedure with multiple tables joined
>   together then the Resync Command
>   Property of the form should be set to
>   an SQL statement that selects the same
>   fields as the stored procedure and
>   parameterize the primary key of the
>   table that is designated as the Unique
>   Table.Table.

btw, I found it here:  http://aspalliance.com/989_Migrating_Access_Database_to_SQL_Server.4Table.

Comment: I am not sure what you wish to do. Have you set the link child and link master fields?

Comment: yes. The form lets you select a record from the master table (an employee), and then lets you type a note into the "notes" table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of using [ResyncCommand](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239886).

Comment: An example adapted from the MSDN link: `SELECT Customers.CompanyName, Orders.* FROM Customers INNER JOIN ORDERS ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID WHERE Orders.OrderID = ?`